# C++ map insert undesired behaviour

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert

consider the following code :

```
// in global space 
int v[50000];

// in a function
int n;
std::cin >> n;
for(int i(0); i < n; ++i)
    std::cin >> v[i];

std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>> m;
for(int i(n-1); i > -1; --i){
    auto it(m.find(m[v[i]]));
    if(it == std::end(m)){
            m[v[i]] = i; // (1)
            // m.insert({m[v[i]], i}); (2)
            // m.insert(std::make_pair(m[v[i]], i)); (3)
    }
}
std::cout << "map : \n";
for(auto &x: m)
    std::cout << x.first << ' ' << x.second << '\n';
```

suppose we have in input : 3 1 2 3
with using first version of map insert i got the expected result :

3 2

2 1

1 0

however with the second and third one i got :

3 0

2 0

1 0

where they should give the same result ..

Comment: Answers in comments -.-

Answer (score 5):

```
m.insert({m[v[i]], i}); //(2)
```

You have to correct it as follows:

```
m.insert({v[i], i}); //(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> where they should give the same result ..

Nope!

> ```
> m[v[i]] = i; // (1)
> ```

This is right. It's like *MapName[Key] = Value*.

> ```
> m.insert({m[v[i]], i}); (2)
> ```

This is wrong. It's like *MapName.insert({MapName[Key], Value})*.

> ```
> m.insert(std::make_pair(m[v[i]], i)); (3)
> ```

Same here.

Your evaluation of `m[v[i]]` creates the element with key `v[i]` and gives it its default value (`0`) because it doesn't exist yet. The `insert` operation then repeatedly tries to insert an element with key `0`.

We can actually see in [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a036feb0e662785) that the resulting values are not this as you said:

> 3 0
>   2 0
>   1 0

but instead:

> 3 0
>   2 0
>   1 0
>   0 2

In fact you want to do *MapName.insert({Key, Value})*, so:

```
m.insert({v[i], i});
```

Similarly, with the `find` operation:

```
auto it(m.find(m[v[i]]));
//             ^^^^^^^
```

Should be:

```
auto it(m.find(v[i]));
```